# How compare If the types using Generics are the same?

Tags: dart

Suppose I have the class `someClass`

```
class someClass<Generics> {}

someClass<int> a = someClass<int>();
someClass<String> b = someClass<String>();
someClass c = someClass();
```

How I can check if the elements `a,b,c` are the same type (`someClass`) ?

is it possible in Dart?

I tried to use `runtimeType` method, but the types are differents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if some object in the format `MyObj<T>` has an exact generic type `T`.

```
bool isOfExactGenericTypeAs(Object? obj) {
  var runtimeTypeStr = obj.runtimeType.toString();
  var pos = runtimeTypeStr.lastIndexOf('<');
  return runtimeType.toString().endsWith('<${runtimeTypeStr.substring(pos + 1)}');
}
```

To check if some object in the format `MyObj<T>` has the exact same generic type `T` of another object:

```
bool isOfExactGenericTypeAs(Object? obj) {
  var runtimeTypeStr = obj.runtimeType.toString();
  var pos = runtimeTypeStr.lastIndexOf('<');
  return runtimeType.toString().endsWith('<${runtimeTypeStr.substring(pos + 1)}');
}
```

My package: https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections has two extension which lets you use these methods like this:

```
// True
<int>[1].isOfExactGenericType(int);

// True
<num>[1].isOfExactGenericType(num);

// False
<int>[1].isOfExactGenericType(num);

// False
<num>[1].isOfExactGenericType(int);

// True
<int>[1].isOfExactGenericTypeAs(<int>[1]);

// True
<num>[1].isOfExactGenericTypeAs(<num>[1]);

// False
<num>[1].isOfExactGenericTypeAs(<num>[1]);

// False
<int>[1].isOfExactGenericTypeAs(<num>[1]);
```

Note: This is, of course, a horrible hack.

Answer (score 3):

Actually unlike other languages (like Java), Dart does not have type erasure on generics. This means, the objetcs `a`, `b` and `c` in your example **are** different types.

If you

```
print(a.runtimeType);
print(b.runtimeType);
print(c.runtimeType);`
```

you will get

```
SomeClass<int>
SomeClass<String>
SomeClass<dynamic>
```

The generic type is not erased at runtime. If you want to check if all objects are of type `SomeClass`, you could use

```
print(a is SomeClass);
print(b is SomeClass);
print(c is SomeClass);
```

This will give you

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: If I have just have `a` (SomeClass<int>) and `b` (SomeClass<String>) is possible to get just `SomeClass`?